# React - Filter array get all messages

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

Im trying to make a React filter to filter the messages for each person. But im out of ideas trying to get the right result....

```
0: {first_name: "dk", last_name: "k", email: "k@l.nl", message: "Email Sent", name: "test camp"}
1: {first_name: "asdfk", last_name: "lksdfl", email: "kk@l.nl", message: "Email Sent", name: "test camp"}
2: {first_name: "asdfkl", last_name: "lksdf", email: "salkdf@live.nl", message: "Email Sent", name: "test camp"}
3: {first_name: "asdklfjlk", last_name: "laskdfjlksdf", email: "ksdfsdaf@l.nl", message: "Email Sent", name: "test camp"}
4: {first_name: "asdfkl", last_name: "lksdjfkl", email: "kk@sds.nl", message: "Email Sent", name: "test camp"}
5: {first_name: "asdfkl", last_name: "lksdjfkl", email: "kk@sds.nl", message: "Clicked Link", name: "test camp"}
```

What I wanted to achieve is that i get a list of messages for each user. for user "asdfkl" it would be messages [email sent, clicked link].

Any ideas how to achieve this in react?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to filter your set by `first_name`:

```js
const people = [ { first_name: 'dk', last_name: 'k', email: 'k@l.nl', message: 'Email Sent', name: 'test camp' }, { first_name: 'asdfk', last_name: 'lksdfl', email: 'kk@l.nl', message: 'Email Sent', name: 'test camp' }, { first_name: 'asdfkl', last_name: 'lksdf', email: 'salkdf@live.nl', message: 'Email Sent', name: 'test camp' }, { first_name: 'asdklfjlk', last_name: 'laskdfjlksdf', email: 'ksdfsdaf@l.nl', message: 'Email Sent', name: 'test camp' }, { first_name: 'asdfkl', last_name: 'lksdjfkl', email: 'kk@sds.nl', message: 'Email Sent', name: 'test camp' }, { first_name: 'asdfkl', last_name: 'lksdjfkl', email: 'kk@sds.nl', message: 'Clicked Link', name: 'test camp' } ]; 

let getMessagesByFirstName = (name, data) => {
  let result = data.filter(x => x.first_name.includes(name)) || []
  if(result.length) {
    result = Array.from(result.reduce((r,{message}) => r.add(message), new Set()))
  }
  return result
}

console.log(getMessagesByFirstName('asdfkl', people))
```

and get all he messages in an array form.

The idea is first to filter via [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then reduce the returned data set to only the messages via [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
The use of the Set is just so we get unique values and do not have duplicates in the final array.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a better approach with reduce:

```
const people = [
  {
    first_name: 'dk',
    last_name: 'k',
    email: 'k@l.nl',
    message: 'Email Sent',
    name: 'test camp'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'asdfk',
    last_name: 'lksdfl',
    email: 'kk@l.nl',
    message: 'Email Sent',
    name: 'test camp'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'asdfkl',
    last_name: 'lksdf',
    email: 'salkdf@live.nl',
    message: 'Email Sent',
    name: 'test camp'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'asdklfjlk',
    last_name: 'laskdfjlksdf',
    email: 'ksdfsdaf@l.nl',
    message: 'Email Sent',
    name: 'test camp'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'asdfkl',
    last_name: 'lksdjfkl',
    email: 'kk@sds.nl',
    message: 'Email Sent',
    name: 'test camp'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'asdfkl',
    last_name: 'lksdjfkl',
    email: 'kk@sds.nl',
    message: 'Clicked Link',
    name: 'test camp'
  }
];

const getEmails = people.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const user = cur.first_name;
  if (!acc[user]) {
    acc[user] = [];
  }
  acc[user] = [...acc[user], cur];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(getEmails);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filteredMessagesList = name => {
    const messagesArray = [];
    personList.forEach(person => {
        if(person.name === name) {
            messagesArray.push(person.message);
        }
    });
    return messagesArray;
}
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value